# Youtrack e-mail channel only reads tickets opened by the same organization

Tags: youtrack

I´ve configured a project in Youtrack Help desk.
I set the redirection in the mail box integration@MyCompanyName.com to MyCompanyName@youtrack.cloud .
The messages received by integration@MyCompanyName.com are redirected to youtrack only if the sender is from the same company/domain.
I´m testing with my personal e-mail myPersonal@gmail.com, the message appears in the mail box integration@MyCompanyName.com, but the message never goes to Youtrack.
I need to read e-mails from any sender, because Its a help desk account.

I´ve tried to configure IMAP directly, allowing untrusted apps and generating an app password, but only messages sent by users from my company are imported.

Does anybody have any tip?

Comment: You can check [processed emails](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/cloud/view-processed-emails.html). If YouTrack fetched it, then it'll show up there with the status details. If you don't see it, then better reach out to the YouTrack support so they can check the logs.

Comment: This page shows that no messages were read. Once, I've tried to send an e-mail directly to MyCompanyName@youtrack.cloud and it showd that the message were read and filtered. But sending to the right mailbox shows no messages found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a ticket with Youtrack support and they oriented me to use IMAP to connect directly the mailbox, but this needs an extra step that is create a rule and select a filter for the folder INBOX.
After that, all the mails sent were read.